# Как можно получить слово в нужном падеже (онлайн api)?

Tags: api, веб-программирование, javascript, online

Требуется online api (посылаешь запрос с словом в им.п. и ед.ч и получаешь в ответ слово в падеже P и числе N) для JavaScript для перевода слов в нужные падеж и число. Где такое можно найти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Где такое можно найти?

Что в гугле, что в яндексе- [по первой же ссылке](http://morpher.ru/)

Comment: Искал. Возможно не заметил.